# How to get the collection based upon the wildchar redis key using redis-rb gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redis

The redis objects created using the `redis-rb` gem.

```
$redis = Redis.new
$redis.sadd("work:the-first-task", 1)
$redis.sadd("work:another-task", 2)
$redis.sadd("work:yet-another-task", 3)
```

Is there any method to get the collection that has "work:*" keys?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you just want to build a collection on Redis, you only need one key.

The example you provided builds 3 distinct collections, each of them with a single item. This is probably not that you wanted to do. The example could be rewritten as:

```
$redis = Redis.new
$redis.sadd("work","the-first-task|1")
$redis.sadd("work", "another-task|2")
$redis.sadd("work", "yet-another-task|3")
```

To retrieve all the items of this collection, use the following code:

```
x = $redis.smembers("work")
```

If you need to keep track of the order of the items in your collection, it would be better to use a list instead of a set.

In any case, usage of the KEYS command should be restricted to tooling/debug code only. It is not meant to be used in a real application because of its linear complexity.

If you really need to build several collections, and retrieve items from all these collections, the best way is probably to introduce a new "catalog" collection to keep track of the keys corresponding to these collections.

For instance:

```
$redis = Redis.new
$redis.sadd("catalog:work", "work:the-first-task" )
$redis.sadd("catalog:work", "work:another-task" )
$redis.sadd("work:the-first-task", 1)
$redis.sadd("work:the-first-task", 2)
$redis.sadd("work:another-task", 3)
$redis.sadd("work:another-task", 4)
```

To efficiently retrieve all the items:

```
keys = $redis.smembers("catalog:work")
res = $redis.pipelined do
    keys.each do |x|
       $redis.smembers(x)
    end
end
res.flatten!(1)
```

The idea is to perform a first query to get the content of catalog:work, and then iterate on the result using pipelining to fetch all the data. I'm not a Ruby user, so there is probably a more idiomatic way to implement it.

Another simpler option can be used if the number of collections you want to retrieve is limited, and if you do not care about the ownership of the items (in which set is stored each item)

```
keys = $redis.smembers("catalog:work")
res = $redis.sunion(*keys)
```

Here the SUNION command is used to build a set resulting of the union of all the sets you are interested in. It also filters out the duplicates in the result (this was not done in the previous example).

Comment: Thanks, Actually I've just added on value per collection to make the question simple. But as you said, yes, it will create 3 collection sets. Later I'll add more values in every collection. I can't just create a collection with key `work` coz the app logic needs some uniqueness in every collection, so the example was put in that way. I think I've to re-think it again.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add an example to retrieve the content of n collections. Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I could get it by `$redis.keys("work:*")`.

Comment: Beware: this is a linear operation. If you have millions of keys, it will freeze the whole Redis instance for several seconds.

Comment: @DidierSpezia, then what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: To deal with a collection, see my general answer. Now if you really want to fetch a subset of the keys (i.e. such as KEYS work:*), then you should not do  it directly. You have to maintain a separate collection (for instance a set) containing the keys you are interested in, and then read this collection.